# How to manage Multiple branches on Git

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch

I am working on a project using git where I've been assigned two tasks. Let's assume task A and task B.

I started by forking the project and created a branch named `A` at this point I was not aware I had to do task B. After forking the project I've cloned the project to my local pc.

Next I ran following command:

`git checkout -b A` -- created branch A

I made changes to project as per the requirement then I did the following

`git add *`

`git commit -m "message"`

`git push origin A`

Now I was assigned task B for which I created the branch named `B`.

`git checkout -b B`

Made changes as per the requirements and committed those changes to branch B.

Now the issue is Branch B contains changes also made in A, instead it should follow the main branch plus changes required as per task B. How can I fix this issue? Branch B should follow main branch and changes as per task B on branch B.

I tried `git checkout main` but no such branch exist.

Comment: Before you go any further with this question, you need to decide: are you doing everything directly on GitHub? (This is difficult and probably a bad idea.) Or: did you clone the GitHub repository to your own machine, e.g., a laptop? (This is usually the way to go.) If you *did* clone your GitHub fork, there are now *three* repositories involved: two on GitHub (the original and your fork) and a third on your laptop.

Comment: This is important because *every repository has its own branch names*. When you work with multiple repositories like this, you will *share commits* but you won't *share branch names*.

Comment: So, given that (from your question) there are *three* repositories, it's now important to say: "I have branch B on my laptop" or "I have branch B on my GitHub fork" or whatever. You might (or might not) use the same names in the GitHub fork as on your laptop, but these are different branches!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
# Checkout the master branch
git checkout master

# Create a fix branch
git branch task-b-fixup

# Get history of branch task-b
git log --oneline --graph --decorate task-b

# Cherry pick commits from task-b by repeating the following command
git cherry-pick {{task-b commit hash}}
```

Now, if you want, you could destroy the old task-b branch.

Comment: I can't checkout master branch I am not sure why. I am getting an error `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`.

Comment: That error occurs when the `.git` folder is not present! Please post the output of the `tree -d` command.

Comment: Sorry I was not in the correct directory now I can switch to master branch. Let me try out the solution.